# Cannot Edit Local File in VS Diff Mode

Tags: visual-studio

If I compare a local file to its parent file, I can edit, in the right pane of VS, the local file if the file extension is `cpp` or `h`. If I compare text files that have a different extension (e.g. `file.abc`), the comparison is against a **copy of the local file** (e.g. `file - copy 2.abc`), not against the local file itself, and the copy is not editable.

The file extension **must be registered with the c++ editor** (Tools | Options... | Text Editor | File Extension).

The following command line generates copies of the compared files.

`devenv /diff c:\file.abc d:\file.abc` compares `c:\temp\file copy.abc` to `c:\temp\file copy 2.abc`.

Is it possible to have the same behavior as for `cpp` & `h`?

Comment: I recommend editing the question to just focus it on the VS stuff and remove all the THG portions which now seem irrelevant.